# Viewcontroller.m doesn't execute code

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have just made a project, and I have used code from this site : http://codewithchris.com/iphone-app-connect-to-mysql-database/

And the problem is, of course, is ViewController.m. The code in it dosen't execute, I have tried putting `NSLog(@"Test With NSLog");` in ViewController.m but nothing happens. The JSON thing from the "site_url" is all good.

Here's all the code:

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "HomeModel.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate,     HomeModelProtocol>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *listTableView;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Location.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
HomeModel *_homeModel;
NSArray *_feedItems;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

// Set this view controller object as the delegate and data source for the table view
self.listTableView.delegate = self;
self.listTableView.dataSource = self;

// Create array object and assign it to _feedItems variable
_feedItems = [[NSArray alloc] init];

// Create new HomeModel object and assign it to _homeModel variable
_homeModel = [[HomeModel alloc] init];

// Set this view controller object as the delegate for the home model object
_homeModel.delegate = self;

// Call the download items method of the home model object
[_homeModel downloadItems];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)itemsDownloaded:(NSArray *)items
{
// This delegate method will get called when the items are finished downloading

// Set the downloaded items to the array
_feedItems = items;

// Reload the table view
[self.listTableView reloadData];

}

#pragma mark Table View Delegate Methods

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of feed items (initially 0)
return _feedItems.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath      *)indexPath
{
// Retrieve cell
NSString *cellIdentifier = @"BasicCell";
UITableViewCell *myCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

// Get the location to be shown
Location *item = _feedItems[indexPath.row];

// Get references to labels of cell
myCell.textLabel.text = item.username;

return myCell;
}

@end
```

HomeModel.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol HomeModelProtocol <NSObject>

- (void)itemsDownloaded:(NSArray *)items;

@end

@interface HomeModel : NSObject <NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<HomeModelProtocol> delegate;

- (void)downloadItems;

@end
```

HomeModel.m

```
#import "HomeModel.h"
#import "Location.h"

@interface HomeModel()
{
NSMutableData *_downloadedData;
}
@end

@implementation HomeModel

- (void)downloadItems
{
// Download the json file
NSURL *jsonFileUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"site_url"];

// Create the request
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:jsonFileUrl];

// Create the NSURLConnection
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
}

#pragma mark NSURLConnectionDataProtocol Methods

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
// Initialize the data object
_downloadedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
// Append the newly downloaded data
[_downloadedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
// Create an array to store the locations
NSMutableArray *_locations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// Parse the JSON that came in
NSError *error;
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_downloadedData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

// Loop through Json objects, create question objects and add them to our questions array
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.count; i++)
{
    NSDictionary *jsonElement = jsonArray[i];

    // Create a new location object and set its props to JsonElement properties
    Location *newLocation = [[Location alloc] init];
    newLocation.username = jsonElement[@"Username"];
    newLocation.email = jsonElement[@"Email"];
    newLocation.money = jsonElement[@"money"];

    // Add this question to the locations array
    [_locations addObject:newLocation];
}

// Ready to notify delegate that data is ready and pass back items
if (self.delegate)
{
    [self.delegate itemsDownloaded:_locations];
}
}

@end
```

Location.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Location : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *username;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *email;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *money;

@end
```

Location.m

```
#import "Location.h"

@implementation Location

@end
```

Comment: Are your Interface objects (either IB or Storyboard) connected to the code.

Comment: Is this your first VC? Have you set the rootViewController to this ViewCOntroller?

Comment: Have you checked the view in the storyboard has the class ViewController.m? When your app launches what color screen do you see? Try putting a breakpoint at the very beginning of the viewDidLoad function

Comment: @logixologist I'm using Storyboard

Comment: @codingVoldemort This is my first time doing this, and Yes

Comment: @itedi I did what you said about setting a breakpoint and the code dosen't stop. And I see white with black lines

Comment: Pull up the story board and select the View Controller. Go to View--> Utilities --> Show Attributes Inspector.  The top of the very far right window you have a number of icons. Click on the 3rd one called Custom Class. My guess is that it probably says the name of the object like UIViewController or UITableViewController and not the name of the actual class that has the code. So for example if your class is called MyVeryCoolController that name needs to be in the storyboard so it knows what code to use for that controller.

Comment: @logixologist Still don't works... :/